# Is it possible to extract sub-pictures from a master-picture with gimp scripting

Tags: scripting, gimp

I have the following Picture:

[image]

And you guessed it: I want to extract all the little pictures into separate files. What I want to now:

1. Is it possible to do this with one of Gimps scripting interfaces?
2. Would you use “Batch-Mode”, “Script-Fi”, “Plug-ins” or something else I am not aware of?
3. If yes: I have no experience with Gimp scripting: How much effort will it be to learn the needed skills?

Of course any additional pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best ways to script GIMP is using the Python language - so that you have full acess to any other resources Python can tap, in addition to GIMP's API

In the case above, I'd proceed to place image guides over the grid lines,  then using the "slice"  plug-in- it will generate a GIMP image for each table cell. Then use Python, could even be the interactive console, to loop through the images and perform extra operations (like saving) on them.

To see what can be done melodramatically in GIMP, check the help->Procedure Database menu entry. 
If you don't have a "filters->python-fu" menu entry, you gave to install the GIMP-Python environment. For Linuxes it is available as a separate package, For windows, you will have to google for it, as it requires the install of 3 or 4 different components in the correct order. (Hopefully when GIMP 2.8 - the next version  is out - th Python environment will come built-in on windows installs)